# always have one option selected even if users click the clearIcon with MUI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Right now there is a default option but if I click a clear icon, this unchecks all of the options.

I want to have one option always selected.
How can I achieve this with Autocomplete material-ui?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBox";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;
const clearIcon = <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      open={true}
      limitTags={1}
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      clearIcon={clearIcon}
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      defaultValue={[top100Films[0]]}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </li>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Search Labels" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
];
```

Attempt

I switched `value` to `defaultValue` but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBox';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;
const clearIcon = <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = React.useState([top100Films[0]]);
  const handleChange = (e, newValue, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clear') return setDefaultValue([top100Films[0]]);
    setDefaultValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      open={true}
      limitTags={1}
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      clearIcon={clearIcon}
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      value={defaultValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </li>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Search Labels" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
];
```